# Magit: don't ask to save changes

Tags: magit

When I have a buffer with unsaved changes, magit asks for each and every action to save that changes.

I didn't save that changes on purpose, so is there a way to disable this behaviour? My Magit should simply ignore unsaved changes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Magit has a variable called `magit-save-repository-buffers` that is by default set to `t`. Try setting it to `nil`

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation for the `magit-save-repository-buffers` variable, which describes the behavior for values `t`, `nil`, and `'dontask`.

> Documentation: Whether to save file-visiting buffers when appropriate.
>
> If this is non-nil then all modified file-visiting buffers belonging
>   to the current repository may be saved before running commands, before
>   creating new Magit buffers, and before explicitly refreshing such
>   buffers.  If this is `dontask' then this is done without user
>   intervention, if it is t then the user has to confirm each save. 
>   `dontask' is the recommended setting.